# tabular whole page lr

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have some problems with creating a table. I'd like to have a table with no borders that fills the total text width, with 2 columns aligned right and left respectively. However, I can either make a table with the total text width or aligned left and right but not both. I tried to do it with `>{\raggedright \arraybackslash}m{0.05\linewidth}` with adding a 3rd. empty column, but I can't make it to align left or right.

Could someone please help ?

basic code:

```
\begin{tabular}{lr}
a & b \\
  & d
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First with `tabularx`, you can make a column `r`ight aligned by

```
>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X
```

while `X` column type takes care of the column width automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}  %% jusr for demo
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
    Left & Right\\
    Left & Right
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Next with `tabular*`. Here we use `lr` columns but the space in between is filled with a total width equal to `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}  %% jusr for demo
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    Left & Right\\
    Left & Right
  \end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

With `p` column type and `tabular`, we have to calculate the width of columns and then issue `\raggedleft` for second column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}  %% jusr for demo
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
                  >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}
    Left & Right\\
    Left & Right
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No need of fancy computations or additional packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe} % for the test

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lr@{}}
left & right\\
again & again and again
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

[image]